# Facebook API obtain photos

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am looking for a fairly simple way of obtaining pictures from Facebook.  I have a client that has pictures that he uploads to Facebook quite often.  He wants a way for those pictures to be populated on the website that I built for him a while ago.  I thought doing it with google drive would be a fairly easy solution for him, but it has not been.

I am trying to create a simple page that grabs his folders that the images live in with the graph api, without having to do a lot or having users logged in.  What is going to be the easiest way of doing this?

I tried the explorer for the api and have the following code.

```
<?php

  $request = new FacebookRequest(
  $session,
  'GET graph.facebook.com',
  '/me',
  array(
    'fields' => 'id,name,photos{album}'

  )
);

$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
/* handle the result */

?>
```

I for now would just like to be able to echo the elements so that I can learn how it works, after that I can refine it.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you need to authorize the user who owns the photos with the user_photos permission, else you cannot get any data or any photos.

Comment: right now I am just trying to get photo's that I own to show up I am very new to using API's and this is still confusing for me do you have a small example that I could look at?

Comment: the docs offer a lot of examples, make sure you read about facebook login

Comment: I have been reading them.  There is mention that it is not required or that maybe it was not at one point for someone to be logged in to see them.  Is my understanding of this flawed or has it actually changed?  If it has then that might be at least part of it that I am missing.

Comment: you MUST authorize a user to get ANY data of his account. without authoriztion, you cannot get ANY data. that is a fact.

Comment: First of all, you need to clarify whether your client uploads those photos to their personal profile, or a Facebook page.

Comment: Okay so I don't think I did a very good job of clarifying what I am wanting to do as CBroe pointed out.  What I really want is to do is get the pictures that my instructor posts to his "personal" Facebook feed and that go into his albums.  I want to then take those pictures and display them on his site without him having to do anything else.  I do not want the pictures that are in a user's profile to be on that page only the ones that are in his albums.  I was hoping to avoid plugins, but I realize that this may not be possible.  I also do not mind having the person viewing the site to login.